# WiFi connectivity problem on iPhone6s

Tags: iphone, network, wifi

I don't really know that is this forum is best for asking this question but if there is any other place to ask this question Please let me know.

We have an issue at home where the iPhone not connect to my WiFi network or if got connected, it will not stay for long, i have to stay at the same place after connecting it. 
I have tried so many ways to get rid of this problem but not getting the right solution for this.

iPhone 4s & 7+ works perfectly fine.

I have tried so many solutions for this but none of them worked for me.

1. Changed my IP address
2. Restarted my WiFi device
3. Restarting iPhone
4. Forgetting and re-adding network

Comment: Have you tried resetting all network settings?  This will delete all you wifi names & passwords and is the next step in troubleshooting wifi problems.  Go to `Settings -> General -> Reset -> Reset Network Settings`.  Make sure you know your wifi names and passwords before you do this.

Comment: If as you say `i have to stay at the same place after connecting it. ` indicates signal strength problem or crowding (to many other wifi on same channel). Open your router and see if iPhone is connected. Then look at crowding, or just select another channel and try.